# Using keytool for a chat room

Tags: java, keytool

I am developing a chatroom with all the security features- like public key encryption (public and private key pairs for every chat client) and also a certificate authority that signs their public keys. Can anybody tell me how I can use the keytool facility to generate public private key pairs in java? I know the basic keytool commands, but how do I use them in java?

Answer (score 0):

Here is about [Java Keytool commands](http://nl.globalsign.com/en/support/ssl+certificates/java/java+based+webserver/keytool+commands/)